# How do I ensure my USB drive isn't infected?

Tags: malware

I was advised recently by someone on here to reinstall my OS after being infected by belombrea dot com. However, in order to reinstall I needed to download Windows 10 on a USB drive. Now I'm afraid the USB drive itself might be infected. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Given that the website in question seems to be related to adware, I highly doubt that the hardware/firmware of your USB drive itself would be targeted. That is a much more elaborate attack than a persistent browser redirect, and may have to be tailored to your specific type of drive.

As mentioned in comments, if you still do not trust it, a new USB drive is not a big investment.

Answer (score 0):

If the malware was an executable designed for Windows and written on your USB. I think a good solution is to put it on a Linux based OS in Live CD for example and format it.
However, if your USB firmware has been modified, this solution will be useless.
You must keep in mind that modify the USB firmware needs to have low-level languages programming skills and the attack must **target the specific device and brand**.

That fact: you need now to ask yourself if hack your USB device have a real interest in investment cost/value of hack. Most of malware and particularly adware no needs to do that because there is enough victims in the world...

*I will finish by add a quick reflection : As your USB firmware is not open source and Free, how can be sure the device have no backdoor from the factory...*

Comment: As for if the firmware is modified, I was really tempted to provide the tongue-in-cheek answer of "hit it with a hammer, then pop it in the microwave for 30s"

Comment: Less tongue in cheek, downloading the installer onto a factory fresh USB drive is as cheap as $10 these days.  So that definitely provides an upper bound on the cost required to avoid re-infection.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I ensure my USB drive isn't infected?

There is no way to *ensure* beyond all doubt the drive isn't infected. However, based on the context of your question there seems to be no reason you should be worried about any persistent USB malware.

If you want to make yourself feel better you could format the USB drive... But this will probably already be done by the Windows USB installation creation process.

You could also purchase a new USB drive, as suggested in other answers or comments.